# webiopi: html to python to serial

Tags: javascript, python, html, webiopi

maybe it is an easy fix, maybe I messed up badly. I am lost. Thank you in advance for any help you can give me!

So, I have a raspberry pi 2 b+ that has to be mounted on a rover (RC Crawler). I decided to use WebIOPi but I can't find anything useful.

My project should work like this: HTML/JS -> PYTHON -> SERIAL TX -> ARDUINO 
I already have everything I need, and a PWM shield for raspberry is quite expensive here.

I managed to get two sliders displaying on my HTML and arduino is ready to receive the command strings. But somewhere in between something is not working.

The full codes are at the bottom, here are just some pieces:

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
<input type="range" min="1" max="179" value="90" class="slider" id="myRange" width="500"></div>
```

Here I have one of the two sliders.

```
<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("steering");
var slider2 = document.getElementById("myRange2");
var output2 = document.getElementById("throttle");
var vs = slider.value;
var vt = slider2.value;
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
output2.innerHTML = slider2.value;
slider.oninput = function() {
    steering.innerHTML = slider.value - 90;
    webiopi().callMacro("new_steering",vs);
}
slider2.oninput = function() {
    throttle.innerHTML = slider2.value - 90;
    webiopi().callMacro("new_throttle",vt);
}
</script>
```

here I run a script that writes the value on the HTML page formatted as a -89 to 89 range. And I call a WebIOPi Macro called new_steering, passing the value vs (vs should be the value of the slider, from 1 to 179).

```
@webiopi.macro
def new_steering(nsv):
    f = open("slog.txt", "a+")
    f.write(nsv)
    news_string = "S{}".format(nsv)
    f.write(news_string)
    serial.writeString(news_string)
    f.close()
```

Within the python code I have the macro that read the incoming value, writes it to a text document (not working nor needed, just to check if it receives the variable), it creates a string with S as leading character and tries to send it trough serial port

Something is wrong. I don't know what and how bad. Please help! My tiny head is boiling.

I have set up WebIOPi like this:

```
[GPIO]

[~GPIO]

[SCRIPTS]

botler1 = /home/pi/botler1/python/interface.py

[HTTP]

enabled = true
port = 8786

passwd-file = /etc/webiopi/passwd

prompt = "BOTLER1_hello"

doc-root = /home/pi/botler1

welcome-file = index.html

#------------------------------------------------------------------------#

[COAP]
enabled = true
port = 5683
multicast = true

[DEVICES]

usb1 = Serial device:ttyACM0 baudrate:9600

[REST]

gpio-export = 17
gpio-post-value = true
gpio-post-function = false

[ROUTES]
```

this is the HTML- Web interface

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>WebIOPi | Light Control</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webiopi.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
webiopi().ready(function() {
    // Create a "Light" labeled button for GPIO 17
    var button = webiopi().createGPIOButton(17, "Light");

    // Append button to HTML element with ID="controls" using jQuery
    $("#controls").append(button);

    // Refresh GPIO buttons
    // pass true to refresh repeatedly of false to refresh once
            webiopi().refreshGPIO(true);
});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
    button {
        display: block;
        margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        width: 160px;
        height: 45px;
        font-size: 24pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
    }

    #gpio17.LOW {
        background-color: Black;
    }

    #gpio17.HIGH {
        background-color: Blue;
    }
    .slidecontainer {
width: 100%; /* Width of the outside container */
}

/* The slider itself */
.slider {
-webkit-appearance: none;  /* Override default CSS styles */
appearance: none;
width: 100%; /* Full-width */
height: 25px; /* Specified height */
background: #d3d3d3; /* Grey background */
outline: none; /* Remove outline */
opacity: 0.7; /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */
-webkit-transition: .2s; /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
transition: opacity .2s;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slidecontainer">
<input type="range" min="1" max="179" value="90" class="slider" id="myRange" width="500"></div>
<div align="center"><p>Steering: <span id="steering"></span></p></div>
<div class="slidecontainer">
<input type="range" min="1" max="179" value="90" class="slider" 
id="myRange2" width="500"></div>
<div align="center"><p>Throttle: <span id="throttle"></span></p></div>

</div>
<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("steering");
var slider2 = document.getElementById("myRange2");
var output2 = document.getElementById("throttle");
var vs = slider.value;
var vt = slider2.value;
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
output2.innerHTML = slider2.value;
slider.oninput = function() {
    steering.innerHTML = slider.value - 90;
    webiopi().callMacro("new_steering",vs);
}
slider2.oninput = function() {
    throttle.innerHTML = slider2.value - 90;
    webiopi().callMacro("new_throttle",vt);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the python file

```
import webiopi
import datetime

GPIO = webiopi.GPIO

# setup function is automatically called at WebIOPi startup
def setup():
    nosense = 1

# loop function is repeatedly called by WebIOPi 
def loop():
    # retrieve device named "serial" in the config
    serial = webiopi.deviceInstance("usb1") 
    # write a string
    #serial.writeString("some text")

    webiopi.sleep(1)

@webiopi.macro
def new_steering(nsv):
    f = open("slog.txt", "a+")
    f.write(nsv)
    news_string = "S{}".format(nsv)
    f.write(news_string)
    serial.writeString(news_string)
    f.close()

@webiopi.macro
def new_throttle(ntv):
    d = open("tlog.txt", "a+")
    d.write(ntv)
    newt_string = "T{}".format(ntv)
    d.write(newt_string)
    serial.writeString(newt_string)
    d.close

def destroy():
    nosense = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever tried serial comm independently of webiopi?
I have read that serial comm is not conventional as used to be, so, try it first of all.